# discourse can't send email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, bitnami, discourse

i installed a discourse on AWS bitnami [edu3d.co](https://edu3d.co). I did the following things but still can't send the login verification email.

- config the discourse by this instruction https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/discourse/configuration/configure-smtp/
- in AWS, request email sending limits
- in AWS, verify my email identity,
- in AWS, send test email (it is correct)
- create my credential
- checked spam boxes (no email)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I guess problem is that I set the username and password wrongly.

```
smtp_address = ''
smtp_port = 587
smtp_domain = 'edu3d.co'
smtp_user_name = ''
smtp_password = ''
smtp_enable_start_tls = true
smtp_authentication = login
```

If you have problem in setting smtp for the discourse installed on AWS EC2 bitnami. You can do the following checks.

- 1) check whether your VM instance can connect the smtp server (test if smtp_address and smtp_port are correct)

I found 25 is not responding and 465 sometimes broke too, 587 works well.

- 2) check whether your username and password set correctly. 
  AWS provides this instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html

**How I find the problem**

I really can't figure out why the smtp setting is 'correct' but i just can't receive the email. So I changed to gmail, the setting is a bit easier than AWS SES. After change, I received the email immediately but it says the login method is not secure so Google blocked it. This proves the smtp setting is working. And according to previous test, my VM instance can connect to the smtp server. So there should have something wrong in the smtp setting.

I go to AWS SES, intending to check the my credential. But I can only create a new one. So I did, then I found I misunderstood the username and password. After change, the email is working. Great!

The following instruction is very helpful!
https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/discourse/configuration/configure-smtp/